# Split $\cos(x-y)$ into $\phi(x)\phi(y)$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

As written in the topic I try to find a function $\phi$ that satisfies
split $\cos(x-y) = \phi(x)\phi(y)  $  $x,y \in \mathbb{R}  $.

So far I'm stuck with:
$\phi(x) = \cos(x)+ \sin(x)$

$(\cos(x)+ \sin(x)) \cdot (\cos(x)+ \sin(x)) = \cos(x-y) + \sin(x+y)$

Answer (score 3):

No such function exists.
We'd have that for each $x\in \Bbb R$

$$1 = \cos(0) = \cos(x-x) = \phi(x)^2 \implies \phi(x) = \pm 1$$

But of course, $\cos(x-y)$ can assume other values.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is such function.

Then $\phi(x)^2 = \cos 0 = 1 \implies |\phi(x)| = 1$. So pick any solution of the equation $x-y = \frac \pi 4$. Then  $|\cos \frac \pi 4| = |\phi(x)\phi(y)| = 1$ and finally $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} = 1$.

Therefore, there is no such $\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Any function $g(x,y)$ of the form $g(x,y) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$  has the property that
$$
\left|\begin{aligned}
g(a,a)\quad&g(a,b)\\
g(b,a)\quad&g(b,b)
\end{aligned}\right| = 
\left|\begin{aligned}
\phi(a)\phi(a)\quad&\phi(a)\phi(b)\\
\phi(b)\phi(a)\quad&\phi(b)\phi(b)
\end{aligned}\right| =
\phi(a)^2\phi(b)^2 - \phi(a)^2\phi(b)^2
=0
$$
for any values $a,b$.  Now try $a=0,b=\pi/2$ using $g(x,y) = \cos(x-y)$:
$$
\left|\begin{aligned}
\cos(0-0)\quad&\cos(0-\pi/2)\\
\cos(\pi/2-0)\quad&\cos(\pi/2-\pi/2)
\end{aligned}\right| =
\left|\begin{aligned}
1\quad&0\\
0\quad&1
\end{aligned}\right| = 1
$$
Therefore, $\cos(x-y)$ cannot be written in that form.

---

**Remark**
The standard product to sum formula  is
$$
\cos(x-y) + \cos(x+y) = 2 \cos x \cos y
$$